# C# why am I getting zero count back?

Tags: c#, string

I was hoping someone could help. I am making a deck of cards in C# and create an instance there are no cards in the pack. I have never coded in c# but I understand java well. I am pretty sure this would work in java so If anyone could let me know where I am going wrong that would be so helpful.

```
public class PackOfCards : IPackOfCards
{
    private int cardsInPack;
    private Collection<ICard> pack = new Collection<ICard>();
    public int Count {
        get {
            return this.cardsInPack;
        }
        set {
            this.cardsInPack = value;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<ICard> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return pack.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    { 
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Create()
    {
        String [] values = {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
        String [] suits = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"};
        int cardsInPack = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i<suits.Length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<values.Length; j++, cardsInPack++){
                pack.Add(new Card(values[j], suits[i]));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        Random num = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < pack.Count-1; i++) {
            int ran = num.Next(pack.Count);
            ICard temp = pack.ElementAt(ran);
            pack.RemoveAt(ran);
            pack.Insert(ran, pack.ElementAt(i));
            pack.Insert(i, temp);
        }
    }
    public ICard TakeCardFromTopOfPack()
    {
        int topCard = 0;
        ICard cardRemoved = pack.ElementAt(topCard);
        pack.RemoveAt(topCard);
        return cardRemoved;
    }
}
```

interface ipackofcards:

```
public interface IPackOfCards : IReadOnlyCollection<ICard>
{
    void Shuffle ();
    ICard TakeCardFromTopOfPack ();
}
```

Interface Icard:

```
public interface ICard
{
    String getValue();
    String getSuit();
    String toString();
}
```

class card;

```
public class Card : ICard
{
    private String value;
    private String suit;

    public Card(String v, String s)
    {
        value = v;
        suit = s;
    }
    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    public String getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return value+" of  "+suit;
    }
}
```

interface ipackofcardscreator

```
public interface IPackOfCardsCreator
{
    IPackOfCards Create ();
}
```

class packofcardscreator:

```
public class PackOfCardsCreator : IPackOfCardsCreator
{
    public IPackOfCards Create()
    {
        PackOfCards p = new PackOfCards();
        p.create();  //addition, please note that i have tried this but to no avail
        return p;

    }

}
```

Thank you everyone who has helped, it is much appreciated. I will just have to leave it as one of life's unanswered questions. I believe everything I have done is right but perhaps something else is wrong such as IDE or computer. Bad carpenter always blames his tools and well i'm a bad carpenter.

Comment: i did have it in before but it didn't work

Comment: The problem is that you are using to many things from Java.

Comment: @spaga Please have a look at my comment it contains some best practices.

Comment: just reading it just now. I wasn't sure why i had the count to be honest I really didn't understand the stupid collector thing which took me hours to get passed. But there is a problem when I run the program it just does not do anything.

Comment: If you are going to do anything meaningful with that, the Value/Rank should be integer.  Also, a `Stack<T>` will work better as a Deck than a collection.

Comment: nothing meaningful at all, also i was given skeleton code that had used collection. If this were me i would have just used array [] and I could have done it in ten minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you are taking too many things from Java for it to work. Secondly why would you need your own counter if `Colllection` class already contains a count which is accurate. So I would implement `Count` property as follows:

```
public int Count
{
    get
    {
        return pack.Count;
    }
}
```

Next, I think the `Create` method should be `static` and return new instance of the class:

```
public static PackOfCards Create()
{
    PackOfCards newPack = new PackOfCards();
    String[] values = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
    String[] suits = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs" };

    for (int i = 0; i < suits.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
        {
            newPack.pack.Add(new Card(values[j], suits[i]));
        }
    }
    return newPack;
}
```

And in interfaces I would C#pify the method names:

```
public interface ICard
{
    String GetValue();
    String GetSuit();
    String ToString();
}


public class Card : ICard
{
    private String value;
    private String suit;

    public Card(String v, String s)
    {
        value = v;
        suit = s;
    }
    public String GetValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    public String GetSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }
    public override String ToString()
    {
        return value + " of " + suit;
    }
}
```

So my `Main` method could look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PackOfCards cards = PackOfCards.Create();
    Console.WriteLine(cards.Count);
    ICard c = cards.TakeCardFromTopOfPack();
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Also I would consider implementing the implicit conversion from `ICard` to `Card`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer a lot. I have made the changes but as I have said the program does not run.

Comment: @spaga Do you get any errors as for me it runs correctly?

Comment: @fsacer Nice changes +1

Comment: well that is a relief. I guess it is just the IDE that is really causing problems.

Comment: @spaga http://pastebin.com/5CKtY9AH this is full working source code for .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: +1, I was thinking the same thing about duplicating `Count`. `Suit` should probably be an `enum`, `value` could be too, or a plain integer.

Comment: @dreamlax Yeah nice catch enums would be much better.

Comment: such a relief, at least I know it  works, maybe not on my computer but at least  someones.

Comment: @spaga Another offtopic one but if you don't have a compiler at hand you can yust use tutorialspoint's coding ground which contains all the compilers you might one soo you can compile just in about any programming language you can into executable files. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm

Comment: @spaga As you see it works, so could you put a tick next to my answer?

Comment: Yes, sorry that you needed to ask there.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is you are getting 0 when calling Count property of your PackOfCards class. The reason I'm thinking like that is your implementation of Create method. In that method you declared new variable with name cardsInPack, which will override cardsInPack field. That field is used in your Count property and you always will get 0 when you will call that property. 
Try to update your Create method like following:

```
public void Create()
{
    String [] values = {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
    String [] suits = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs"};
    this.cardsInPack = 0; //your code is: int cardsInPack = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<suits.Length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<values.Length; j++, this.cardsInPack++){
            pack.Add(new Card(values[j], suits[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

## [Edit]

One more thing to @fsacer 's answer

```
public interface IPackOfCards : IReadOnlyCollection<ICard>
{
    void Shuffle ();
    ICard TakeCardFromTopOfPack ();
    public int Count { get; }
}


public interface IPackOfCardsCreator
{
    IPackOfCards Create();
}
public static class PackOfCardsCreator : IPackOfCardsCreator
{
    public static IPackOfCards Create()
    {
        return PackOfCards.Create();
    }
}
```

And then you can use PackOfCardsCreator class to create new PackOfCards:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IPackOfCards cards = PackOfCardsCreator.Create();
    Console.WriteLine(cards.Count);
    ICard c = cards.TakeCardFromTopOfPack();
    Console.WriteLine(c.toString());
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to subtract one in Remove, too.

Comment: From @msmolcic 's answer you can see that Count property and cardsInPack fields are 0, which says to users of your class that your PackOfCards is empty, however, as you can see from his screenshot, there are cards in pack field. So you need to update your Create method in order to solve the problem.

Comment: good spot which will definitely help. however, for some reason nothing works when I add the p.create() in the packofcardscreator file. there must be something wrong somewhere else that is not visible from code.

Comment: @Grdaneault, thank you for your comment. As he said you'll need to update your TakeCardFromTopOfPack method as well

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can't you get Count? Maybe it's because your PackOfCardsCreator class is returning IPackOfCards interface, which doesn't have Count property?

Comment: Why in the right mind would anyone keep own count if `Collection` already contains one?

Comment: @fsacer, Maybe just for experimental or learning purposes? Anyways, that's design problem. Current problem is implementation problem in my opinion

Comment: @Umriyaev I agree, but if you fix a design problem you can make an implemention a lot easier to implement, code more readable and easier to understand.

Comment: So basically I have a test script set up for me to run and when I run the test file there are no outputs. The tests just seem to run for a while then stop with no answers. I know that the test file is not wrong because it had worked previously.

Comment: What are you checking in your test script? What properties are you using? I'm pretty sure that the problem is in Count property. You should add it to your IPackOfCards interface.

Comment: @Umriyaev Looking at your edit I think this would not work because you are not using `static` also in the interface I would use just the get as I don't use set for `Count` anywhere.

Comment: @fsacer Did you check PackOfCardsCreator class? I changed it to static

Comment: @Umriyaev I did see that, however you didn't do that for the method `Create` so it wouldn't work. Also you would need to return this in it `return PackOfCards.Create();`.

Comment: @fsacer Ah yeah, sorry. My fault.

Answer (score 1):

The `PackOfCardsCreator` class has a method called `Create` that return an instance of a `PackOfCards` object. When you create this object, since you haven't defined any constructor, the default constructor would be executed and the field of your class will get either their default values or the values you have specified. Regarding the `pack`:

```
private Collection<ICard> pack = new Collection<ICard>();
```

You create an empty collection of `ICard` objects. But you will say I have defined a method that is called `Create`. Yup, you have done so. However, when someone creates a pack of cards, like below:

```
var packOfCardsCreator = new PackOfCardsCreator();
var packOfCards = packOfCardsCreator.Create();
```

Internally in the `Create` method you have this:

```
PackOfCards p = new PackOfCards();
```

I think you get the point.

> And what can I do ?

You could just call the method `Create` after the creation of a `PackOfCards` object, like below:

```
public IPackOfCards Create()
{
    PackOfCards p = new PackOfCards();
    p.Create();
    return p;
}
```

Comment: yes sorry i have changed it so much that I keep forgetting to change it all. In packofcardscreator i did have p.create(); and then i returned p. Should this have worked because it didn't. I have a feeling that maybe something structurally is wrong with the code.

Comment: @spaga not a problem. and you still get an empty deck of cards?

Comment: yip, I don't know why. I have changed it to a constructor and have tried to leave it as void but does not seem to work. I am running it through tests which for some reason do not finish.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating instance of an object `PackOfCards` and calling `Create` method afterwards, it should work, at least it's looking fine to me:

[image: Pack of cards]

Comment: i am using sharpdevelop ide could this be the problem? really clutching at straws. Structurally is the code ok?

Comment: @spaga I doubt it's the cause of the problem. In C# we're writing method names starting with capital letter and you should override object ToString() method instead of implementing your own toString method inside an interface. Other than that, it looks fine to me.

Comment: @spaga A bit offtopic, but I would recommend a Visual Studio Community as I guess you are a student and it's free for students and small dev teams or for those who are learning and not making commercial products yet. Also it's made for C# from the C# creator Microsoft and it contains best tools. You can get it here https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx.

Comment: Thank you, I was of the notion i had to pay for it. I get it downloaded now. Hopefully that solves the problem. You have been a great help .